# Unexpected behaviour of read method for multiprocessing case

Tags: python, file, multiprocessing, critical-section

I am reading from the same file with multiple processes in binary mode. The file is firstly opened in the parent process, and then the child processes are created. The actual code for reading a given part of the file is:

```
def _line(self, n: int) -> str:

    offset = self._lineOffsets[n]
    lineSize = self._lineSizes[n]

    self._criticalSectionLock.acquire()

    line = b""
    
    try:
        self._datasetFile.seek(offset)
        while len(line) < lineSize:
            # because read may return less than required number of bytes we must read in while loop
            block = self._datasetFile.read(lineSize-len(line))
            line += block

            if len(block) == 0:
                raise IOError(f"Failed to read whole sample on line {n} (indexed from 0).")
    finally:
        self._criticalSectionLock.release()

    return line.decode("utf-8")
```

The problem is that the read method does not always return the whole chunk. Not arbitrary, it always occurs for the same chunk. When I edit the code in the following way:

```
def _line(self, n: int) -> str:

    offset = self._lineOffsets[n]
    lineSize = self._lineSizes[n]

    self._criticalSectionLock.acquire()

    line = b""
    
    try:
        while len(line) < lineSize:
            # because read may return less than required number of bytes we must read in while loop
            self._datasetFile.seek(offset+len(line))
            block = self._datasetFile.read(lineSize-len(line))
            line += block

            if len(block) == 0:
                raise IOError(f"Failed to read whole sample on line {n} (indexed from 0).")
    finally:
        self._criticalSectionLock.release()

    return line.decode("utf-8")
```

the problem disappears. What happened is that the file offset was increased by the size that I really wanted to read, even I actually got a smaller chunk.

So I would like to ask how that can happen?

To cut off some questions in advance, I am giving here some points why the file is not read in a standard line by line approach:

- large file
- storing the whole file in memory is not a desirable approach
- need non-sequential access to lines
- reading in binary mode proved itself to be faster
- known sizes of lines and their offsets in advance